# Carcassone scoring for a city with a mayor and a cathedral

Tags: carcassonne

How do you score a city that has both a mayor and a cathedral? We ended up making each tile worth 3 points for the cathedral plus 1 point for each shield/banner in the city for a total of 6 points per tile.

Was that correct?

*I'm playing with the Inns and Cathedrals and the Mayors and Abbeys expansion packs.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mayor doesn't affect the *number of points* received for completing a City.  The Mayor only affects **WHO** might get the points.  If someone has a meeple in a city and you get your Mayor in the city, the mayor counts as the number of pennants in that city.

So if the City had 0 pennants, then your mayor would be 0 and the other meeple would be 1, allowing them to have 'more' meeple.  If there was 1 pennant, then you would tie and both get the score.  If there were 2 or more pennants, than you would have more meeple (the number of pennants) and would 'win' and get all the points your opponent getting nothing.

The Cathedrals as you've noticed changed values from 2 points/tile and pennant to 3 per.  So a city with 8 tiles and 2 pennants would go from 20 points to 30 points.  Who ever has the most meeple in the city gets all the points (tie both get the same)

Answer (score 2):

The mayor counts for the number of shields in comparison to other meeple in the same city. So if a city has 3 shields, you have a mayor and another player has two meeple, you get the points.

The cathedral increases the mulitplier for the tiles from 2 to 3. A 12 tile city without a cathedral gives 24 points, with a cathedral it gives 36 points.